The cursor on the touchpad is not moving
ts_print can accurately print the absolute coordinates of the touchpad, but the cursor on the desktop does not move. Using xev to test, when moving the cursor to the xev test box with a USB mouse, there is no response in the xev terminal. I have installed touchegg and can confirm that multi-finger gestures work properly.
Additionally, I can confirm that the touchpad shortcut switch in the settings is enabled.

I suspect there might be an issue with Xorg, is there any way to debug it?

“Touchpad: kernel bug: Touch jump detected and discarded.
See https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/1.20.0/touchpad-jumping-cursors.html for details.”
This message indicates that a touch jump issue has been detected and discarded by the kernel. The provided link directs you to a detailed explanation of the problem and potential solutions.
